# versioning of the content

Tags: php, versioning

I am developing a PHP/mysql package to  add/edit questionnaire.. I want some pakage to save the versions of edits of questions and rollback to previous version. can anyone suggest such package..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PropelORM` has a versionable behavior by which you could do just that. [Behavior versionable](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/Behaviors/versionable).

Although I might suggest you try to approach the problem differently.